# JQuery AJAX Post Not work on FF , Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code but is not working on FireFox and Safari Browser.

But works fine and IE and Chrome.

Any ideas ?

```
function formData() {

    var serializedValues = $("#msform").serialize();
    var form_data = {action: 'ajax_data', type: 'post', data: serializedValues, };

    $.post("insert.php", form_data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
        document.getElementById("sucess").style.color = "#006600";
        jQuery('#sucess').show();
    });

    return serializedValues;
}
```

Comment: try removing trailing comma in `form_data` object. That used to break old versions of IE...glad they resolved that one. FF has usually been OK with it though

Comment: I've never heard of that causing problems in anything other than old versions of IE. I doubt it's the problem in FF and Safari.

Comment: Do you get any error messages to speak of?

Comment: @Barmar I agree but the rest of code seems inncoent enough

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is it sending the wrong values to PHP, is it returning the wrong results?

Comment: also what is purpose of `return serializedValues` ?

Comment: The PHP is correct the php save de valeus from de #msform , but only on Chrome and IE browser.

Comment: but Joao there are numerous other things you can check such as the actual request ( is it being sent, what is sent, status etc), errors thrown, possibly you have a form that hasn't been prevented from submitting also. There isn't enough information given

Comment: I use this example http://www.infotuts.com/multi-step-form-with-progress-bar-using-jquery-css3-php/

Comment: Logical steps ... can you console.log serializedValues and form_data just before the post?  Do you get the alert, style change on success, does success show?  What is in response and is there something returned by the function?

Answer (score -1):

Extra comma? Try ...

```
var form_data = {action: 'ajax_data', type: 'post', data: serializedValues};
```

**UPDATE**:

Next logical steps

1. Is there anything listed in the browser's Inspector?
2. Can you console.log `serializedValues` and `form_data` just before the post? Do you get expected values?
3. Do you get the `alert`?
4. Do you get the style change on `#success`?
5. Does `#success` show?
6. What is in `response` and is it what you expected?
7. And, is there something returned by the function?

Comment: Do you really think Safari can't handle the extra comma? I thought it was only a problem in old IE versions.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me ... stranger things have happened.  Better to have solid code, either way.  This could also be something dropping out in the POST, in the AJAX, at the server ... because of incorrectly formatted data.

Comment: There's nothing "unsolid" about the extra comma, it's allowed in the Javascript specification.

Comment: @bamar "unsolid" ... in the sense that i'ts not good code.  There are a lot of things allowed the the JavaScript specifications that may not be good code.  Allowed does not make it right.  The extra comma can cause unexpected consequences.